# Checking APK signature before install through PackageManager.installPackageWithVerification

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I work for a company that is building an app that can programmatically install, update and remove apps (similar to what Google Play already does). There is a business requirement to support installation of only company signed APKs. I understand that CDD allows self-signed certificates. But, keeping the CDD requirement aside, what is the best way to achieve this?

After spending some time on AOSP codebase, I figured that PackageManager provides an API called installPackageWithVerification which can satisfy the requirement to allow installation of apps signed with a specific signature. Following is the signature of installPackageWithVerification API:

```
public abstract void installPackageWithVerification(Uri packageURI,
            PackageInstallObserver observer, int flags, String installerPackageName,
            Uri verificationURI, ManifestDigest manifestDigest,
            ContainerEncryptionParams encryptionParams);
```

It appears that the verificationURI  can be the file URI to the certificate againinst which the APK should be checked. Am I correct? It will be great if someone could please share some more info about this specific API.

Thanks.

Comment: Complex stuff, but this might help a bit: https://github.com/nelenkov/jb-app-encryption/blob/master/src/org/nick/jbappencryption/MainActivity.java#L225